# How to find the length of Success Data in Jquery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, for-loop

I am retrieving list from ajax, when it become success, I wants to add those list values to DropDownList Items, So I want to iterate the `data` until last value and then add it to `DropDownList`

Here is my code What i tried

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    url: "GPCreateCheque.aspx/getOpenRequestNo",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       alert(data.length);

        for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $(".tbDDLReqNo").append(new Option(data.d[i], data.d[i]));
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }

})
```

> In alert box it is showing `undefined`

**UPDATE**

> I return the `list<string>` from `[webmethod]`

Comment: What does you `data` look like ? Try `console.log(data)`

Comment: provide the structure of `data`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia it has a `list<string>`

Comment: JSON.parse(data).length

Comment: @krishnar it doesn't show anything

Comment: @mohamedfaiz alert(data.d.length);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use data.d.length

```
alert(data.d.length);

for (var i = 0; i<data.d.length; i++) {
    $(".tbDDLReqNo").append(new Option(data.d[i], data.d[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `data = JSON.parse(data);` before treating your data like an array. It's just a string up to that point.

Update: if your data is not the array itself, but instead an object that contains an array named *d*, you need to work with that. It depends on your data structure.

Comment: `data` field is for what kind of data we are going to send to server correct?, If I am not wrong, When I alert `data.d[0]`, it is printing the first value of array

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are receiving via Ajax. Usually, you get a string in JSON format. This string needs to be parsed to become a Javascript object. If your data contains an array in Json format, please try this: *alert(JSON.parse(data).length);*  This should give you the length of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the response from network tab in Chrome Developer Console or similar tool. May be response code is 200 but response data is missing.

On the other hand you want to itarete `data` in for loop but you try to append `data.d[i]`. If you want to append `data.d[i]` you have to itarete `data.d` in for loop.